# Firebase for SMS sending

Tags: firebase

Can I use firebase for sending sms without depending on any third party libraries ?
Does firebase have an API for sending sms? I have gone through the firebase web site but couldn't find those information.

Comment: why don't you use the Notification instead of SMS ?

Comment: No, Firebase doesn't have a SMS sending API yet.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @RosárioPereiraFernandes :-)

Comment: Posted @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Firebase doesn't have a SMS sending API yet.