# SMS API with Firebase (FCM)

Tags: android, api, firebase, sms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way for Firebase to send SMS to a specific phone number?
In GCM, there is SMS API like that. But I can't find it on Firebase (FCM) anywhere.
FCM supposed to have everything that GCM can do because FCM will replace GCM.

Based on this, there's still no SMS API for firebase. But the answer is from 2016.
[Firebase for SMS sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277166/firebase-for-sms-sending)

Answer (score 2):

No, Firebase doesn't have an SMS sending API yet but you can use services like Nexmo or Twilio for that. Alternatively, you can use AWS SNS to send SMS.